# Is ihttp a legitimate protocol?

Tags: html, protocols

And if so, what does it do?

I've noticed it in some html written by a former co-worker (so I can't ask the author).  I'd guess it was a typo, except that it's in a couple different places in a couple different templates, used as the source attribute for an image.

For example:

`<IMG height="6" src="ihttp://www.ourdomain.com/images/f2f3f4.gif" width="5">`

The top google results point to some sort of apache/php/mysql installer, but we're running IIS, so I can't imagine that that's related.

Comment: It's specific to Safari on the iPod Touch and iPhone.  ;-)

Comment: @tvanfosson: good one :D

Comment: @tvanfosson: you jest, but it was written by a graphic designer using Dreamweaver on a Mac, which is partly what made me (a lowly .NET guy) think twice and wonder if it might be some artifact of the tools used to create it and thus actually serve some purpose of which I was simply unaware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Typo**. Nothing More.

No such protocol exists. What you are seeing is a classic design pattern called *cut-and-paste*. If I have to guess, I would say that `i` was previously the leading `i` in `images/f2f3f4.gif`.

Comment: At an old place I worked we called this "goat code" after a goatloving copy+paster. Nice guy, but his code made you want to beat him with a hammer.

Comment: Your explanation rings true; even if can't prove it, that's good enough to reassure me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a deliberate use of `ihttp://` --
http://blog.instapaper.com/post/1538890633

(I found this thread while googling how that was done. I haven't found the answer to that yet.)

Comment: Oh great... more protocol handlers for things that are really just vanilla HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

its a typo AND a bug - lucky you!

Answer (score 0):

ihttp is a new protocol being used mainly by Asp.net. It is for dynamic generation of web pages. Try looking at call stacks of asp.net as webpage is developed.

Comment: Can you discuss the accepted answer as well? Is it not a typo? If not, can you link to documentation/about pages?